# In MySQL How Do I Create a Single Column that Adds a Decimal Place and Return Null Values as 0?

Tags: mysql, formatting

Essentially, I would like to combine these two lines of code

```
SELECT truncate(cast(amount as decimal)/100,2) as amount, 
ifnull(amount,0) as amount from charge;
```

[image]

Comment: Not clear what "adds a decimal" means.  Please show what type charge.amount is (ideally, output of `show create table charge`) and some sample data and desired results for that sample data

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there. Use `IF()` instead of `IFNULL()`

```
SELECT IF(amount, truncate(cast(amount as decimal)/100,2) ,0) as amount from charge;
```

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_if